# Installing Trial version

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop, license

I need the Abode CS 4 software for only 50 days. Unfortunately it allows me a trial of only 30 days.

Here's what I plan to do. I have two partitions on my computer - one with vista and one with win 7. Can I first install Adobe s/w trial on Vista and after 30 days install it on Win 7. Will it work and is it legal to do so?

Thanks. Any other alternatives are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can install a trial version at different times on different machines (for the first time) and at each instance use it for the trial period starting from the time of install.

However, if you choose to 'move' to a different installation after the trial period to continue using the software, you will lose all configuration and state developed on the first installation. If that is not a problem, this should work.

And, if that is not a problem, you could just 'kill' the first Windows installation, reinstall the OS and Trial software again and get another 30 days trial period.

The loss of previous installation context is the 'limit' introduced by the trial case.
If you want to get rid of that limitation, you should purchase the software.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it work and is it legal to do so?

Yes. No.

> Any other alternatives are welcome

Pay for the software.

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible** to do it. When you install trail software, they ask for your email address so you can't use the same address.

**Alternative to Photoshop CS4:**
http://www.getpaint.net/

Comment: That's only to download the software, the trial functionality is built into the programs.

Answer (score 0):

try GIMP. its an open source very advanced image editor

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps slightly less grey, if you have the Adobe Photoshop CS4 trial already you could  try that for 30 days and then upgrade to the [Adobe Photoshop CS5 trial](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=photoshop) for the next 30 days? Once you're finished you could do a review on the differences :)